# How to create a Couchbase bucket using Python client?

Tags: couchbase

Looking at Couchbase Python client, I don't see how you can specify bucket type in order to create `couchbase` bucket type.

The [client](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/client.py#L107) doesn't allow you to specify bucket type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively it looks like it is missing in the wrapper, but you should be able to achieve this using the following code:

```
couchbase = Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "Administrator", "password")
#get the rest interface
rest = couchbase._rest()
rest.create_bucket(bucket='myBucket',
                   ramQuotaMB=160,
                   authType='sasl',
                   saslPassword='password',
                   replicaNumber=0,
                   bucketType='couchbase')
```

You can send couchbase or memcached

I will log a bug and that in the high level API.